# Having issues with claimsprincipal in .net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core

I have been trying to make a system similar to one that i had in .net 4.5 in core to no success.  I am still trying to fully grasp core but figured key items would still be there.  My end goal is to have a principal returned with custom claims and have it last the whole session or memory for about 15 minutes before it rechecks.  Here are my issues that i can't seem to overcome and search the internet for to no success.

1. The claimstransform runs every time i execute an action but wasn't sure if there was a way to move this to a session level event if one exists.
2. The ClaimsPrincipal i have only gives me a sid for the AD groups instead of name and I haven't found a way to query AD for that as the Novell option wont work i am using windows auth and have no access to the password the user is using for there ad account login.
3. In the past i have used extended classes of ClaimsAuthenticationManager/ClaimsAuthorizationManager while instantiating FederatedAuthentication in the Global.ascx in .net but cant seem to translate that to core.

Sample of my current code:

```
    public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity cidentity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
            //IQueryable<Claim> claims = cidentity.Claims.AsQueryable();
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

            cidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("TestClaimAdd", "Test Worked"));
            cidentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ApplicationClaimTypes.UserID, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            cidentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, principal.Identity.Name));

            claims.AddRange(cidentity.Claims);

            //foreach (var claim in claims)
            //{
            //    var name = claim.Subject.Name;
            //}

            //cidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("TestClaimAdd","Test Worked"));

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TEST", ClaimTypes.Name, ApplicationClaimTypes.ApplicationRole);

            var myPrincipal = new ApplicationClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            //principal.AddIdentity(identity);

            return Task.FromResult((ClaimsPrincipal)myPrincipal);
        }
    }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I "think" what you're after is Windows Authentication in a Net Core Application? Microsoft provide a standard way of doing this already as part of the framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I am already using windows authentication in my application.  But i am trying to add custom claims that are web application specific that wouldn't be in AD.  The purpose behind this is to add items that i can then use for Authorization on the site.  The reason in .net framework i instantiated the federation was so once it hit the site with an authenticated user i could then add my custom claims to it.  I consumed the existing, added mine then returned that to the thread and context.  I feel i am overthinking this as i know there is a major difference between core and full framework.